# Does anyone remember a short live-action film from the Bay Area called The Tower?

Tags: story-identification, movie, short-film

When I was a kid in San Francisco - circa 1984 or so - my mother took my sister and me to a sort of underground artists collective party. There was a post-punk, avant garde band playing there called *The Lizards*(?), and a short film was shown at some point. I believe it was called "The Tower."

In it, a young man awakens in a deserted city, possibly in ruins. He scans the horizon and sees a translucent red tower. He begins to make his way toward it and finds that he is being pursued by a man in an executioner's mask. He runs toward the tower - I *think* getting nowhere fast - with his pursuer getting closer and closer. I remember at one point the executioner grabbing his heel and maybe there being a flash of light.

Comment: Possibly this one; https://toetactic.com/shorts/shorts.html. It's an animated short https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XAsEatsi8lo

Comment: What were the lizards (rock, punk, etc)? What was the name of the gallery where you saw this film? Was it live-action, experimental, avant garde, what?

Comment: It was a live-action short. The Lizards seemed like a post-punk, avant garde type of affair.

Comment: John Lurie had an experimental jazz band called The Lounge Lizards that played the underground, no-wave circuits in the 80s. Not sure if they ever toured SF.